# Проблемы с кодировкой при парсинге на Python

Tags: python, парсер, кодировка, сериализация

до выполнения get вывел title и выводится в консоли в читабельном формате на русском, а как запускаю сервер то там {
"title": "\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430 \u043e\u0442: 596\u00a0000\u20b8"
}
не знаю уже что делать, на странице с которой парсил кодировка UTF-8

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


url = "https://poedem.kz/hotoffers"  # Replace with the actual URL
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
info_div = soup.find("div", class_="hotoffer-item__price")
title = info_div.text.strip()
print("Title:", title.encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8"))


class ExternalInfo(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # URL of the website you want to scrape
        url = "https://poedem.kz/hotoffers"  # Replace with the actual URL

        # Send a GET request to the website
        response = requests.get(url)

        # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse the HTML content of the page
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

            # Find the div with the specified class
            info_div = soup.find("div", class_="hotoffer-item__price")

            if info_div:
                # Extract information from the div
                title = info_div.text.strip()

                # Assume other information is in sibling div elements

                return {"title": title}, 200
            else:
                return {
                    "error": "Div with class 'TVHotResort TVHotTitle' not found"
                }, 500
        else:
            return {
                "error": "Failed to retrieve information from the external website"
            }, 500


api.add_resource(ExternalInfo, "/travel")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения проблемы с кодировкой при парсинге на Python, можно попробовать использовать метод `encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')` вместо `encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")` для преобразования строки в правильный **UTF-8 формат**. Также, можно убедиться, что веб-сайт, с которого ты извлекаешь информацию, **действительно использует UTF-8 для своего контента.**

Пример:

```py
title = info_div.text.strip()
print("Title:", title.encode("latin1").decode("utf-8"))
```

Также, если тебе нужны обработки кириллических символов в `Flask`, можно установить кодировку по умолчанию в файле `app.py`:

```py
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```